# Retrieving a No Caller ID phone number?

Tags: phone, spoofing

I got a call from an unknown number, more specifically, a no caller ID number. I’m not the guy who gets a lot of calls from a no caller ID phone number, and usually, when I got one is typically the hospital, nothing suspicious. I know in Canada and many other countries, carriers allow us to hide our numbers without any additional fee.

I'm currently researching ways to unmake a no caller ID number with Asterisk if possible. After digging online, the topic is not well documented. I know it’s possible, and they are some company that offers this service like [TrapCall](https://www.trapcall.com/) and [Opencnam](https://www.opencnam.com/).

How can I trap a call by myself?

Other mentions: In Canada, it’s **legal** to trap a call but not in all countries.

Comment: "How can I trap a phone call" is a google search term with quite a few hits.